# Java HttpClient 4.x Runnng into somewhat random errors

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to do GET on thousands of URL as quickly as I can. Using the Apache HTTPClient v4.x I can do this but usually end up with around 3-5% of the requests ending up with either host look up failed (<10% of the errors) and the rest either timing out (<10%) or network read errors.

So basically my loop iterates over the URLs and submit the working threads to the Executor service.  Below are the code snippets for the important pieces:

**Executor
--------**

```
public static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(400);   
AppConfig.monitors.forEach((key, monitor) -> {
        results.add(AppConfig.pool.submit(new WebRequest(monitor)));
    }
});
```

Notes:

1. I have tried all ranges between 50-1000 for thread count.
2. I submit it to a Callable thread which returns a future and I iterater over the results in a subsequent loop.

**CLIENT Code
-----------**

```
cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(2);
cm.setMaxTotal(1000);

RequestConfig rc = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setSocketTimeout(4000)
    .setConnectTimeout(4000)
    .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES)
    .setMaxRedirects(1)
    .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
    .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(false)
    .build();
sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .loadTrustMaterial(TrustSelfSignedStrategy.INSTANCE)
                .build();
sslcsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new NoopHostnameVerifier());
client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .setDefaultHeaders(headers)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(rc)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslcsf)
            .disableAutomaticRetries()
            .setRedirectStrategy(DefaultRedirectStrategy.INSTANCE)
```

Notes:

1. All URLs are final and there are neither regular or circular redirects.
2. Also note that I have run these URLs through the HTTPClient one at a time and they work without issue. So in general timeouts should not occur.
3. All of the domain are accessible.

**REQUEST Code
------------**

```
public class WebRequest implements Callable<Monitor> {
    @Override
    public Monitor call() throws Exception {
        HttpRequestBase request;
        HttpContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        request = new HttpGet(monitor.getUrl());
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = WebClient.client.execute(request, context);) {
            request.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: this is common when doing lots of requests - some will inevitably fail.
you could, for example, allow jobs to re-submit themselves (a limited amount of times ...) to the executor for retries.
either some iteration successfully completes the future, or the last attempts completes it exceptionally.

Comment: @radai : This means that I take out disableAutomaticRetries() and even then if some requests failed do you suggest I use a separate HttpClient for retries or the same one?

Comment: One more thing: Regarding "java.net.UnknownHostException", do you think I am getting those because of volume of requests or because of slow DNS lookup?